# Optimal measurement for distinguishing states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-spin

Suppose we have $n$ identical spin-1/2 particles prepared by some machine. Depending on the setting of the machine, either all the particles are in state |$z_+$> or they are all in state |$x_+$ > (each possibility is equally likely, depending on the secret setting of the machine). The task is to find out which of these two situations is the case by examining the ouput of the machine.

As explained in Schumacher and Westmoreland's *Quantum Processes, Systems and Information* (p. 142): "One way to do this is to measure $S_z$ for each particle. If every one yields the result +$\hbar/2$ then we conclude that the state is |$z_+$>, but otherwise we know that it is |$x_+$>. The only possibilty for error is if the setting is for |$x_+$>, but by chance every $S_z$ measurement happens to yield +$\hbar/2$. This happens with probability $P_E=\frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2})^n = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$."

All of this makes sense. However, as part b of the following exercise (this is exercise 7.3 from *Schumacher and Westmoreland*) suggest, the measurement strategy explained above is not optimal.

a) How many particles do wee need to succesfully distinguish the two situations with a probability better than 99.9% using the $S_z$ measurement?

b) What if we use an optimal measurement?

The answer to question a) is n=9.

But what about b)? What is an optimal measurement strategy? How good can we do?

I'm new to the subject and could need some help here.

Comment: Does optimal mean "joint measurement on several - or even all - states"?

Comment: Hi Norbert. Good question, but the book doesn't tell, so I guess it is up for interpretation. The authors only say that the first way of measuring "is not the optimal measurement for distinguishing n copies of |$z_+$> from n copies of |$x_+$>, but it works pretty well". If you can come up with some measurement (be it a joint measurement on several states or even all states) that requires fewer than 9 particles to obtain at least 99,9% likelihood of succes, then I personally would consider the case closed.

Comment: It also depends whether you want ambiguous or unambiguous discrimination.  (That is, do you allow for a 3rd outcome "not sure"? Then you can make the other two outcomes 100% fine.) -- In any case, you should think about the whole state $|\phi\rangle^{\otimes n}$ as one of two big states which are almost orthogonal and think about the optimal measurement in that case.  This just reduces to two almost orthogonal qubits, since the two vectors span a 2-dim space.